# How to check if something is available in one collection before inserting into another collection in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry, I'm a beginner with mongodb.

I've made a collection named professors that looks like this:
 `

```
    {
        "patron_id":"MR.P",
        "day":"monday",
        "start_hour":"8",
        "start_minute":"30",
        "end_hour": "10",
        "end_minute":"0",
        "type":"a"
    },`
```

... And so on with all the weekdays. It describes the available hours of a professor.

How can I check before inserting into another collection named tutoring if the hours in which a student wants to insert the tutoring matches with the available hours of a specific professor.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do it. One of them is, try to get your professor by time range. If the result is not empty, do your thing(insert into another collection).

Let's say you want to find whether your professor available between 8:35 to 9:35

```
db.getCollection('professor').find({
  patron_id: "MR.P",   //Your professor
  $and: [{
    $or: [{
      start_hour: {
        $lt: "8"
      }
    }, {
      start_hour: "8",
      start_minute: {
        $lte: "35"
      }
    }]
  }, {
    $or: [{
      end_hour: {
        $gt: "9"
      }
    }, {
      end_hour: "9",
      end_minute: {
        $gte: "35"
      }
    }]
  }]
});
```

The above one is not a perfect answer. There are lots of problems here. Don't store minutes and hours separately. Especially not as strings. If those were timestamps it would be a lot easier to do.